# Full page floating figure with TikZ overlay in twocolumn document?

Tags: floats, afterpage, wallpaper, atbegshi

I have a peculiar problem with my LaTeX document. I have a `twocolumn` document and would like to include a figure that is spread over an entire new page and contains a TikZ picture (where I can input a given JPG oder PDF image to fill the entire page and overlay it with a white box for the caption).

My failed attempts thus far include:

- The `wallpaper` package, which unfortunately cannot place the image on a new page

  - Combining `wallpaper` with `figure` - doesn't appear to work either.
- The `\vspace` option, which seems very messy. Basically it screws up the DPI of my image so in print the image pixels do not exactly overlap with the printer dots.
- The `afterpage` package, but this doesn't work because my text is `twocolumn` and `\afterpage` apparently gets executed even after just a column break.
- `pdfpages` but that won't let me overlay a caption box

  - `pdfpages` in combination with `\usetikzlibrary[external]` to output the TikZ pictures (background + caption) into a PDF and then include it again, but that doesn't seem to work because `pdfpages` will interrupt the text immediately, not wait and "float" the figure until after the current page.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Basically what I require would seem as simple as placing a command anywhere in the text, and after this page is done, I get a new clear page to place my TikZ picture in, and after that the normal text continues. However this appears impossible to achieve. Am I missing anything?

Thank you for your time,

A13

Answer (score 2):

This solution will use a combination of `atbegshi` for its `\AtBeginShipout` routine to float the image to the next page in a proper manner; `eso-pic` for its `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` routine that will allow us to draw the full-screen pic in the background of the inserted page; and `tikz` to overlay the caption.

A new command is created:

> New command to set full-page figure
>
> Usage: `\fullpagefig{<filename>}{<caption>}`

The filename is sent directly to `\includegraphics`, and the caption is passed to `\captionof` from the `caption` package to create a caption that matches up with the rest of the figures.

The result, for adding a full-page-image somewhere in the first column of the first page, is a new second page as seen below:

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

[image: page3]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{multicol} % For two column
\usepackage{blindtext} % For dummy text

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

% New command to set full-page figure
% Usage: \fullpagefig{<filename>}{<caption>}
\newcommand{\fullpagefig}[2]{%
\AtBeginShipoutNext{ % At the end of the page...
\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox % Ship the current page as is
\stepcounter{page} % Increment page counter to account for new page
% On next page, add the image in the background
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\put(0,0){\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
\vfill\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}
\vfill}}
% tikz picture to include the caption overlay
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \noindent\node[fill=white] 
    at (0.5\paperwidth,3cm) % placement from bottom-left corner of page
    {\begin{minipage}{3in} % width of the box
    % This will provide a caption numbered and styled like the rest of the figures
    \captionof{figure}{#2}
    \end{minipage}};\end{tikzpicture}
}\shipout\hbox{} % Make a blank page to put the picture on
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\blindtext

{\LARGE Place on next page.}
\fullpagefig{example-image-9x16}{This is a caption of the full page diagram.}

\blindtext[4]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

### Edit: For `twocolumn` mode (instead of `multicols`)

The following code works for `twocolumn` mode in the same manner as above.  Note, the two solutions do not seems to be interchangeable in either direction.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % For dummy text

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

% New command to set full-page figure
% Usage: \fullpagefig{<filename>}{<caption>}
\newcommand{\fullpagefig}[2]{%
\AtBeginShipoutNext{ % At the end of the page...
\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox % Ship the current page as is
% On next page, add the image in the background
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\put(0,0){\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
\vfill\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}
\vfill}}
% tikz picture to include the caption overlay
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \noindent\node[fill=white] 
    at (0.5\paperwidth,3cm) % placement from bottom-left corner of page
    {\begin{minipage}{3in} % width of the box
    % This will provide a caption numbered and styled like the rest of the figures
    \captionof{figure}{#2}
    \end{minipage}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\vbox{\thispagestyle{empty}}\clearpage % Make a blank page to put the picture on
}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

{\LARGE Place on next page.}
\fullpagefig{example-image-9x16}{This is a caption of the full page diagram.}

\blindtext[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be almost perfect, thank you very much. I think I only have one issue: I cannot use `multicols`, I need to do it via `twocolumns` in `\documentclass`. For some reason the code produces an error and an empty additional page with just a page number after the figure. Would you happen to know why? In any case many thanks, I'm sure I can come up with a way to make this work based on your example!

Comment: @A13 I have added an edit to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
The `tikzpicture` will sit behind the text if you don't put it on a new page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-9x16}};
\node [fill=white] at (current page.center) {\Large caption text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this will not exactly solve my problem. First of all I would get a forced page break in the middle of a text if I included this "figure" anywhere in the text. To avoid this I would manually have to place this at the very spot in the text where the page ends, and effectively I couldn't make any changes afterwards that affect the amount of text without repositioning the figures. Also, in ´twocolumn´ mode (not multicol) this leads to the figure overlapping with the text on the next page. However many thanks still.